# Should this GET call return 204 or 200 with a body?

Tags: rest, api, http-status-codes

Say we have a rest api which aggregates data about a Person from other services. One of the Aggregator service routes is `GET /person/(person id)/driverinfo` which tells us whether the person is a licensed driver or not, license id, expiry date of license and the number of traffic violations. These data can be picked up by the Aggregator from one or more other services. This api will be used by a web page to show the "driver info" about a person. It will also be tested with automation.

Currently, the api gives 204 no content response for persons who never had a driving license. This is because one of the underlying apis gives a 204 for that scenario. So, it was decided that the Aggregator should do the same.

But, I believe that this is not a good response. Instead, we should return 200 with appropriate values for the fields. For example, licensed=false, licenseId = N.A. etc. when the underlying api gives a 204. I.e. the Aggregator should generate these fields and their values.

Which approach do you think is better and why ?

Comment: Very simple: If the person does not exist in your DB at all, return 204. If they exist but are unlicensed, return 200 with correct info. You shouldn't return info on a record that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[204](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) means something specific in HTTP; it says that the server found a representation of the requested resource, and that representation is zero bytes long.

Therefore, the real question is more like "Should we use a zero byte long message to describe a situation?".  Maybe?  If all of the fields in your message schema are optional, and we are trying to describe a representation that means that all of the fields are taking on their default values, then a zero byte array might be the right way to communicate that.

Within the context of HTTP specifically, the headers themselves are already significant in length (compared to zero), so I wouldn't expect there to be particularly compelling performance reasons to squeeze a signal down to zero length.  For instance, if we were normally passing around [application/json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), I would expect that sending an empty object or array to be much more cost effective than sending nothing at all.

Comment: Why do you expect that sending an empty object or array is more cost effective than returning nothing ? Also, are there any authoritative guidelines on when to return a particular response code ?